# How to remove "cluster-40926" from my dataroot in moodle

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, moodle

Path of moodledata in Moodle is

`/nas/wp/www/cluster-40926/securityorg/test_moodle.`

> Here is the code

```
$dir = dirname(__FILE__);
echo "Full path to this dir: " . $dir;
```

> Output:

```
Full path to this dir: /nas/wp/www/cluster-40926/securityorg/test_moodle
```

But this creates an error `"Fatal error: $CFG->dataroot is not configured properly, directory does not exist or is not accessible! Exiting"`
cluster-40926 folder donot exits so
I thnk if I can remove cluster-40926 from the path, problem will be solved.
**Please help, Thanks in advance**

Comment: move it out of cluster-40926 folder :)

Comment: cluster-40926 folder donot exits

Comment: Are you saying `dirname(__FILE__)` is making up the existence of this one directory? is that it? Are you sure about what you are saying?

Comment: yes i am 100% sure. i check to find what is my moodle data path n i got this output

Comment: If your actual directory root is /nas/wp/www/securityorg/test_moodle, your error is saying you should set `dataroot` property of the object instantiated on `$CFG` properly, because it seems to diverge.

Comment: i kept a test file in the inside the datamoodle folder

Comment: yes,$CFG->dataroot is not configured because of "cluster-40926" extra

Comment: The question doesn't make any sense. The Moodle data path is set in `$CFG->dataroot` in `config.php`. Incidentally, it shouldn't be in the www folder, it should be below eg: `/nas/wp/securityorg/test_moodle` and it should be writeable by the apache/www user. The function dirname(__FILE__) just prints the current folder, the 2 aren't related.

Comment: yes. i kept moodledata inside test_moodle

Comment: actually my datamoodle and test_moodle are in same location, and to find the path i kept the testfile.php inside datamoodle and there is code above then i run http://hostname/moodle/testfile.php

Comment: no one have any idea?? m waiting. Russell sir i hope u have some solution. I will me highly thankful and  appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot find the real answer, i again reinstall the new version of moodle and problem is solved. If any one face this problem plz reinstall the moodle.

Answer (score -2):

The moodle data directory and the web folder must be separate. Also the moodle data directory must be outside of the www folder.

https://docs.moodle.org/27/en/Installing_Moodle#Create_the_.28moodledata.29_data_directory