# Can we enable and disable cluser?

Tags: php, wordpress, moodle

How to disable Cluster ?

**Location of my file shows 
/nas/wp/www/cluster-40926/securityorg/test_moodle**
 Here is the code

```
$dir = dirname(__FILE__);
echo "Full path to this dir: " . $dir;
```

**Output:**

```
Full path to this dir: /nas/wp/www/cluster-40926/securityorg/test_moodle
```

**How to remove cluster-40926 from my path directory.**

Comment: That's great, get in touch with your hosting provider and tell them that.

Comment: is there any way to remove from code or something ??

Comment: Why do you need to? Trust that that is the correct path.

Comment: it creates me problem  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32254524/how-to-remove-cluster-40926-from-my-dataroot-in-moodle?noredirect=1#comment52390865_32254524

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to just remove it you could use [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php), because it is always the same, it is easy to find and you can just replace it with nothing!

```
preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $string);

$new_dir = preg_replace('-40926', '' , $dir);
```